# G19 Mediakeys not working on Ubuntu 20.04 but on 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, shortcuts, multimedia

I have a Logitech G19 Keyboard with multimedia keys (Play/Pause, Volume+/-, etc.).
They work fine on my private Workstation which runs Ubuntu 18.04LTS, but not on my Working Notebook, running Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

On both Machines/OSs the "Multimedia Shortcuts" are present:
[image]

xinput list

```sh
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08E0:00 06CB:CD97 Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08E0:00 06CB:CD97 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ZLY ZELOTES GAME MOUSE                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ G19 Gaming Keyboard                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ G19 Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G19 Gaming Keyboard Keypad       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GN Netcom A/S Jabra EVOLVE 20 SE MS       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput test (vol +/- pressed):

```sh
xinput test 14
key press   123 
key release 123 
key press   123 
key release 123 
key press   122 
key release 122 
key press   122 
key release 122
```

showkeys (vol +/- pressed):

```sh
showkey -k
KB-Modus war ?UNBEKANNT?
[ Wenn Sie das unter X probieren, muss es nicht funktionieren, 
  da der X Server ebenfalls von /dev/console liest. ]

Drücken Sie eine Taste (Programmende 10 s nach dem letzten Tastendruck) …
Tastencode  28 losgelassen
Tastencode 115 gedrückt
Tastencode 115 losgelassen
Tastencode 115 gedrückt
Tastencode 115 losgelassen
Tastencode 115 gedrückt
Tastencode 115 losgelassen
Tastencode 115 gedrückt
Tastencode 115 losgelassen
Tastencode 115 gedrückt
Tastencode 115 losgelassen
Tastencode 114 gedrückt
Tastencode 114 losgelassen
Tastencode 114 gedrückt
Tastencode 114 losgelassen
Tastencode 114 gedrückt
Tastencode 114 losgelassen
Tastencode 114 gedrückt
Tastencode 114 losgelassen
Tastencode 114 gedrückt
Tastencode 114 losgelassen
```

Has any one a clue why the dont work on my laptop?
For me there is no logical reason why they dont work.
On both machines the key press is detected. On both the shortcuts for Multimedia is present.

Any hint?

PS: The buttons on the Jabra headset dont work either.